# Lookups in VB.NET Bogging Down LDAP Server

Tags: vb.net, ldap

My DBAs have informed me that one of my applications is really bogging down one of our LDAP servers.  I've looked at the code several times, but I can't see any way to limit the amount of times I have to hit LDAP.  So now I've decided to look at the way that I am actually obtaining the data to see if there is a better way.  I did not develop the actual data model I'm using, and I'm not certain what the System.DirectoryServices.Protocols library is all about.

I would really appreciate it if someone who is more familiar with using .NET LDAP providers could lend me some advice.  Here is the function I'm using to look up entries in our LDAP server:

```
    <DirectoryServicesPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Unrestricted:=True)> _
    Public Overloads Shared Function GetSearchResultEntry(ByVal connection As LdapConnection, ByVal searchDirectoryPath As String, ByVal filter As String, _
                                          ByVal attributes As String(), ByVal scope As Protocols.SearchScope) As SearchResultEntry

        If connection Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("connection", "An ldap connection must be provided in order to search for a directory.")
        End If

        If Strings.IsNullOrBlank(searchDirectoryPath) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("A directory path must be provided in order to search for a directory.", "searchDirectoryPath")
        End If

        If Strings.IsNullOrBlank(filter) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("A search filter must be provided in order to search for a directory.", "filter")
        End If

        Dim resp As SearchResponse = CType(connection.SendRequest(New SearchRequest(searchDirectoryPath, filter, scope, attributes)), SearchResponse)

        If resp.Entries.Count > 0 Then
            Return resp.Entries(0)
        End If

        Return Nothing

    End Function
```

Is it possible that maybe the .NET LDAP provider is a bit slow?  If anyone has some code examples of how they are hitting LDAP in their shops that would be great.

Anyway, thanks in advance for your help.

Thanks,
CM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You only ever care about 1 entry.  That code looks like it would return all the results for a particular query.  You might try hunting around for a single-result query style.
2. Failing that, I doubt there's much you can do to make this particular bit a code easier on the server.  You might see if there's some way you can call this function less often- perhaps by caching the results.